# Embed google map from a link in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a map in this link . and I am following this tutorial on google maps
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

but what I can't understand is how to make the map open on the location I have here in this link
https://maps.google.com/?ll=26.293723,50.186512&spn=0.004146,0.007639&t=m&safe=on&z=17

sorry if this seems trivial, I am just new to android

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i would recommend you to stop reading that tutorial because the [Google Maps API version it uses is deprecated.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/)

That said, and specially if you are starting from scratch, i would start reading the new [Google Maps Android API V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) documentation.

According to the URL you have posted, the location you want to go is 26.293723, 50.186512 with a Zoom level of 17. Don't know what the spn parameter is.

You can accomplish this by setting the camera position on the GoogleMap object, using the [newCameraPosition](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory#newCameraPosition%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition%29) method:

```
 GoogleMap map = // <Get it from your fragment>
 LatLng point = new LatLong( 26.293723, 50.186512);
 CameraPosition position = new CameraPosition( 0, point, 0, 17F );
 map.newCameraPosition(position);
```

You can also do it with a nice flying animation with the method [newLatLngZoom](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory#newLatLngZoom%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng,%20float%29):

```
 GoogleMap map = // <Get it from your fragment>
 LatLng point = new LatLong( 26.293723, 50.186512);
 map.newLatLngZoom(point, 17F);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the link I notice you have the lat-long values of the location. Pass your latitude and longitude [as extras](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) to the activity in which you display the Map. Use these values to create a [GeoPoint](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint) which you can pass to [`setCenter()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapController#setCenter%28com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint%29) and/or [`animateTo()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapController#animateTo%28com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint%29) using your `MapController`.

```
controller.setCenter(geoPoint);
controller.animateTo(geoPoint);
```

[Here's more info](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapController) on how to use these methods.